# How can we force canvas to stay still

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, canvas

How can one force a canvas to remain still while you draw on it on android phones?
We have a project in Ionic, where the below code is used to allow the end user to draw on a canvas element, but when he starts drawing, the page scrolls with him.

Strange enough though, the code stops the form from scrolling up and down if the user drags left or right, but if they move their finger up or down before going left or right, the page scrolls with their draw movements, and they end up with basically nothing being drawn...

Does anybody see how I can force the scrolling to hold while the user draw's on the canvas?

```
//employer_signature_canvas setup
var employer_signature_canvas = document.getElementById("employer_my_canvas");
var ctx = employer_signature_canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "#222222";
ctx.lineWith = 2;

// Set up mouse events for drawing
var drawing = false;
var mousePos = { x:0, y:0 };
var lastPos = mousePos;
employer_signature_canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        drawing = true;
  lastPos = getMousePos(employer_signature_canvas, e);
}, false);
employer_signature_canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
  drawing = false;
}, false);
employer_signature_canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
  mousePos = getMousePos(employer_signature_canvas, e);
}, false);

// Get the position of the mouse relative to the employer_signature_canvas
function getMousePos(employer_signature_canvasDom, mouseEvent) {
  var rect = employer_signature_canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: mouseEvent.clientX - rect.left,
    y: mouseEvent.clientY - rect.top
  };
}

// Get a regular interval for drawing to the screen
window.requestAnimFrame = (function (callback) {
        return window.requestAnimationFrame || 
           window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
           window.msRequestAnimaitonFrame ||
           function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
           };
})();

// Draw to the employer_signature_canvas
function renderemployer_signature_canvas() {
  if (drawing) {
    ctx.moveTo(lastPos.x, lastPos.y);
    ctx.lineTo(mousePos.x, mousePos.y);
    ctx.stroke();
    lastPos = mousePos;
  }
}

// Allow for animation
(function drawLoop () {
  requestAnimFrame(drawLoop);
  renderemployer_signature_canvas();
})();



    // Set up touch events for mobile, etc
employer_signature_canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
        mousePos = getTouchPos(employer_signature_canvas, e);
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousedown", {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY
  });
  employer_signature_canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);
employer_signature_canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {});
  employer_signature_canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);
employer_signature_canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
  var touch = e.touches[0];
  var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
    clientX: touch.clientX,
    clientY: touch.clientY
  });
  employer_signature_canvas.dispatchEvent(mouseEvent);
}, false);

// Get the position of a touch relative to the employer_signature_canvas
function getTouchPos(employer_signature_canvasDom, touchEvent) {
  var rect = employer_signature_canvasDom.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: touchEvent.touches[0].clientX - rect.left,
    y: touchEvent.touches[0].clientY - rect.top
  };
}

// Prevent scrolling when touching the employer_signature_canvas
document.body.addEventListener("touchstart", function (e) {
  if (e.target == employer_signature_canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
  if (e.target == employer_signature_canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
document.body.addEventListener("touchmove", function (e) {
  if (e.target == employer_signature_canvas) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: I would try using the :focus selector on the canvas element in your css and lock the scrolling with overflow: hidden in your class declaration

Comment: Can you share your html code as well?

Answer (score 0):

In your template (ionic page) you can use css to remove bounce and rubberband effects:

```
<ion-content no-bounce class="no-scroll"><ion-content>
```

in your scss:

```
.no-scroll .scroll-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    float: none;
}
```